# Ajax post adds parameters to home link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm going to start off that I'm not really experienced in web development, so excuse if this question sound rather dumb or the solution is obvious but I can't seem to find it on this site or google. Basically I have an HTML form and want to post data to a PHP script which mails the data to a specific email address. This is the HTML code:

```
<form id="contact-form" name="contactform" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <p class="contact-name">
      <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" value="" name="name"/>
      <label class="error" for="name" id="name_error">This field is required.</label> 
    </p>
    <p class="contact-email">
      <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" value="" name="email"/>
      <label class="error" for="email" id="email_error">This field is required.</label> 
    </p>    
    <p class="contact-message">
      <textarea id="message" placeholder="Your Message" name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
      <label class="error" for="message" id="message_error">This field is required.</label> 
    </p>
    <p class="contact-submit">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_button" class="button"> 
    </p>
  </fieldset>        
</form>
```

This is the jQuery & Ajax code to validate the data:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.error').hide();
    $(".button").click(function() {
        //validate process  
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        if (name == "") {
            $("label#name_error").show();
            $("input#name").focus();
            return false;
        }
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        if (email == "") {
            $("label#email_error").show();
            $("input#email").focus();
            return false;
        }
        var message = $("textarea#message").val();
        if (message == "") {
            $("label#message_error").show();
            $("textarea#message").focus();
            return false;
        }
    });

    var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "_include/php/contact.php",
        data: dataString,
    });
    return false;

});
```

The problem that occurs here is not the fact that the JS code doesn't run but the post adds the parameters to the current link like: http//website.com/index.html?name=test&email=email&message=msg

But I need it to add the parameters to my PHP file which is located at _include/php/contact.php

Update: So I've tried various answers and thanks for the great replies but I'm still stuck. I can choose to set the action of the form to the PHP file but that means that my page is refreshed and that is something that I want to avoid. The other js scripts didn't seem to change the fact that the parameters are added to the wrong link..

Comment: $( "#contact-form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
/***Check for Error****/
/**if ok***/
event.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'url',
    data : {
        $('#contact-form').serialize(),
       
    }
}
});

Answer (score 3):

Your ajax request is not within the `$('.button').click()` event. It is triggered even without clicking the button. Thus, now the button is triggering the native form submit which has the `action=""` and therefor will append the formdata as a GET request.

Change the javascript code so the formlogic is applied on `$('form').submit()` instead of the button click event; This will increase logic in your code and you disable the full native functionality of the form by return false;

Answer (score 0):

The "action" attribute of the form needs to be set to the php page that you want to submit the form to like:

```
 <form id="contact-form" name="contactform" action="/php/contact.php">
```

Comment: Unless his intent is to use AJAX instead of default form submission, which is what it looks like from his code.

Comment: This works, but my intent was to use Ajax so the page wouldn't have to refresh.

Comment: If you wish to use AJAX and override the default form submit behaviour then consider using [`.ajaxForm`](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Answer (score -1):

I've not tested it, but the snipplet below show the basic setup I normally use.

```
$('#contact-form').submit(function(event){
    var form = $(this);
    if (isContactFormValid()) {
        postData(form.serialize());
    }
    event.preventDefault();



    function isContactFormValid() {
        //Some logic here
        return true;
    }
    function postData(data) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "_include/php/contact.php",
            data: data
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This still adds the parameters to the 'home link', and doesn't execute the contact.php

Comment: Just tried in the console while at SO. And here it tries to post to `http://stackoverflow.com/_include/php/contact.php`. So I'm going to need some more information. What other libraries do you use, version of jQuery, do you use `ajaxPrefilter` ect?

Comment: @DaanOlislagers `event.preventDefault()` provides the same functionality in this case.

Comment: I use jQuery 1.9.1, don't use anything Ajax related. But that does make me think: Do I need to import a special Ajax library in order to use it?

Comment: `$.ajax` is a part of jQuery, so as long as jQuery is added to the page it should be a problem. However you could try `$.post('_include/php/contact.php', data);` instead of the `$.ajax` to see if the error still is the same.

Comment: The $.post still posts it to index.html

Comment: @TimKranen Try the current version, changed it a bit to correctly reflect your original code, (always preventing the default submit action), and added `#` to the jQuery selector, so it correctly matches the form.

Answer (score -2):

Probably you need `event.preventDefault()`

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: He returns `false`, that's equivalent.

Comment: In the last code example of atomman you're still not using return false.

Comment: @DaanOlislagers You dont need to use `return false`, `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` yields the some functionality. [SO explaining the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)